# Is there a better (British) English dictionary available for TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio, dictionaries

I am using the default en_GB dictionary that comes with TexStudio. It seems to be identical to the one distributed with OpenOffice [here](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/node/3814) (at least from the filesize). However it seems to miss a lot of words such as `forecasted` or `aggregator`.

Is there a more comprehensive one available for download?

Comment: I guess you can always add these entries to your personal dictionary and eventually you'll have one good enough...

Comment: If you click on the word with right button and choose *always ignore* then you will not have the word checked anymore.

Comment: Yes I can obviously add them myself but I wouldn't know if they're correct unless I check them myself online whenever they're highlighted. Its obviously ok to work with, but I wondered if anyone knew of a better one.

Answer (score 3):

The dictionaries used by TeXstudio are the same Hunspell ones used by many other projects. You could try the 'extended' en_GB dictionaries provided for [Firefox/Thunderbird](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/). However, I'm not sure any of these are significantly better/more comprehensive than the standard ones: dictionary work is hard.

Comment: that's a neat trick! I indeed like a lot Thunderbird's dict!