# using Mac OS X dictionaries in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, dictionaries

Is there a way to include Mac OS X built-in dictionary/thesaurus in TeXStudio?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111614/is-there-a-better-british-english-dictionary-available-for-texstudio

Comment: Seems unlikely as TeXstudio is a cross-platform editor, so using 'built-in' OS functions is normally not possible. This may well be a feature request for the editor, which I'm afraid would be off-topic here.

Comment: I was hoping that it is something simple like copy the dictionary file to the right folder. Unfortunately, Mac OS dictionaries are stored binary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580539/looking-for-a-terminal-command-to-parse-macosx-dictionary-data-file

Answer (score 3):

TeXstudio can only handle Hunspell dictionaries (as they are used in OpenOffice / LibreOffice). A converter/export from OSX dictionary to Hunspell would be the way to go. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of such a tool, but I'm not an expert there.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the TeXworks resources folder should be located inside the Library folder of your Home (user) folder. This is automatically created the first time you run TeXworks, and some default resources are copied there. There should be a dictionaries subdirectory, but it is initially empty. Place the *.dic and *.aff files there, and then re-start TeXworks.

If your dictionary files are wrongly formatted I'm sure you can use some nifty grep script to fix it.

I've found [LaTeX Editor](http://www.latexeditor.org/download_addons.html) hosts downloads for various different dictionaries and they seem to be quite comprehensive.

Comment: The question is about TeXstudio, and using the 'native' OS dictionaries rather than copying stuff from anywhere

Comment: And you couldn't copy the OS's dictionary or point TeXstudio to look at that directory to get it's dictionaries?

Comment: Would not help: the dictionaries are not in the format used by TeXworks (I've not looked at TeXstudio, but I'm very doubtful it can read the Apple Dictionary format).

Comment: To quote my answer "If your dictionary files are wrongly formatted I'm sure you can use some nifty grep script to fix it."

If not, I'm sure there's a repo out there that has downloadable dictionaries

Comment: Quite apart from the fact that might not be easy or allowed (I've not idea what the license on the files is), my reading of the question is that it's about using the built-in OS service with TeXstudio, not simply installing a dictionary file.

Comment: To quote a comment from the questioning party: I was hoping that it is something simple like copy the dictionary file to the right folder. 

My answer is fine, admittedly it turns out that it wouldn't work but it will still be useful to anyone with this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16125/discussion-between-stormie-and-joseph-wright).